# How to make the condition or when selecting dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where index is a date. I want to select the rows, which belong to the dates between
'01-01-2016' and '01-03-2016' or between dates '15-12-2016' and '01-01-2017'.

To do the first part I use the code

```
mask = ((f11.index > datetime.strptime('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')) & (f11.index <= datetime.strptime('01-03-2016','%d-%m-%Y')))
```

and later call the function

```
f11 = f11.loc[mask]
```

Now I cant do it so that I get both conditions, I tried to put a condition with or but it does not work.

```
mask = (((f11.index > datetime.strptime('01-01-2016','%d-%m-%Y')) & (f11.index <= datetime.strptime('01-03-2016','%d-%m-%Y')) or
            (f11.index > datetime.strptime('15-12-2016', '%d-%m-%Y')) & (
                        f11.index <= datetime.strptime('01-01-2017', '%d-%m-%Y')) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` instead of `or`. Also, you can compare string with `datetime` type in pandas:

```
mask1 = (f11.index > '01-01-2016') & (f11.index <= '03-01-2016')
mask2 = (f11.index > '12-15-2016') & (f11.index <= '01-01-2017')

mask = mask1 | mask2
```